# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: android, retrofit

[image]I am stuck in this problem since two days but no luck.

My json response :-

```
{
"status": "ok",
"response": [
{
  "years": [
    {
      "trackers": [
        {
          "uuid": "C8B907F3200A7C1417076FF84060340F2B1EF5BC858AD27B",
          "curriculum": {
            "name": "NAACE Computing",
            "uuid": "ED4FD5452008EEF5DB663FA30939900F649302BCA34816CB"
          },
          "subject": {
            "uuid": "91364ED12003103FC455BF3B2AC45F0F6387D3FC2A258A05",
            "name": "Computing",
            "source": "system",
            "enabled": true
          },
          "group": {
            "uuid": "E824756720013148C56DFFD7DD7A12021403CE0CEAB49ED2",
            "name": "Class 1",
            "type": "class",
            "policy_priority": 6,
            "users_read_only": false,
            "roles_read_only": false,
            "created_by": null,
            "created_on": 1453189156,
            "updated_by": null,
            "updated_on": null,
            "source": "local",
            "group_members": [

            ],
            "hidden": false,
            "member_count": 5
          },
          "created_by_uuid": "AEBB466920005BA2486F0FC9F9AAC10FDF77900C90146CF6"
        },
        {
          "uuid": "E85D0F4C200A79567716AFDCBE3AF404557C4C4CC1F56EB7",
          "curriculum": {
            "name": "Rising Stars Progression Framework",
            "uuid": "ED5783F62008E54D3F9D5F8B48EE46058679BB9C0907BF8A"
          },
          "subject": {
            "uuid": "91364ED12003103FC455BF3B2AC45F0F6387D3FC2A258A05",
            "name": "Computing",
            "source": "system",
            "enabled": true
          },
          "group": {
            "uuid": "EE093F3C20013BAF5B944FFCB2028602613D4CECD876FD34",
            "name": "Class 2",
            "type": "class",
            "policy_priority": 5,
            "users_read_only": false,
            "roles_read_only": false,
            "created_by": null,
            "created_on": 1453125129,
            "updated_by": null,
            "updated_on": 1453189177,
            "source": "local",
            "group_members": [

            ],
            "hidden": false,
            "member_count": 29
          },
          "created_by_uuid": "AEBB466920005BA2486F0FC9F9AAC10FDF77900C90146CF6"
        },
        {
          "uuid": "E86E8507200A77774147DF5DB7DBFC037DDC5D9CFEAF6C02",
          "curriculum": {
            "name": "Rising Stars Progression Framework",
            "uuid": "ED5783F62008E54D3F9D5F8B48EE46058679BB9C0907BF8A"
          },
          "subject": {
            "uuid": "91364EE520031CB80E753FE310D95207FE0C6B1CECB022E9",
            "name": "Mathematics",
            "source": "system",
            "enabled": true
          },
          "group": {
            "uuid": "EE093F3C20013BAF5B944FFCB2028602613D4CECD876FD34",
            "name": "Class 2",
            "type": "class",
            "policy_priority": 5,
            "users_read_only": false,
            "roles_read_only": false,
            "created_by": null,
            "created_on": 1453125129,
            "updated_by": null,
            "updated_on": 1453189177,
            "source": "local",
            "group_members": [

            ],
            "hidden": false,
            "member_count": 29
          },
          "created_by_uuid": "AEBB466920005BA2486F0FC9F9AAC10FDF77900C90146CF6"
        },
        {
          "uuid": "D1D509CC200A754C76FE0FC980F6DA0BE1AA7C8CA9BC0372",
          "curriculum": {
            "name": "Rising Stars Progression Framework",
            "uuid": "ED5783F62008E54D3F9D5F8B48EE46058679BB9C0907BF8A"
          },
          "subject": {
            "uuid": "A6C4DB8F200316613650CF995B835C06B47CA22CDAAC2F62",
            "name": "Reading",
            "source": "system",
            "enabled": true
          },
          "group": {
            "uuid": "EE093F3C20013BAF5B944FFCB2028602613D4CECD876FD34",
            "name": "Class 2",
            "type": "class",
            "policy_priority": 5,
            "users_read_only": false,
            "roles_read_only": false,
            "created_by": null,
            "created_on": 1453125129,
            "updated_by": null,
            "updated_on": 1453189177,
            "source": "local",
            "group_members": [

            ],
            "hidden": false,
            "member_count": 29
          },
          "created_by_uuid": "D185D3E3200058716235DFECB7C58C0604923B9CEBE14382"
        },
        {
          "uuid": "1BD06054200A7043092FBFCF7AF9270FE4D0F1DC368AC671",
          "curriculum": {
            "name": "Rising Stars Progression Framework",
            "uuid": "ED5783F62008E54D3F9D5F8B48EE46058679BB9C0907BF8A"
          },
          "subject": {
            "uuid": "A6C4DB8F200316613650CF995B835C06B47CA22CDAAC2F62",
            "name": "Reading",
            "source": "system",
            "enabled": true
          },
          "group": {
            "uuid": "EE093F3C20013BAF5B944FFCB2028602613D4CECD876FD34",
            "name": "Class 2",
            "type": "class",
            "policy_priority": 5,
            "users_read_only": false,
            "roles_read_only": false,
            "created_by": null,
            "created_on": 1453125129,
            "updated_by": null,
            "updated_on": 1453189177,
            "source": "local",
            "group_members": [

            ],
            "hidden": false,
            "member_count": 29
          },
          "created_by_uuid": "AEBB466920005BA2486F0FC9F9AAC10FDF77900C90146CF6"
        },
        {
          "uuid": "E892B134200A70221D6EDF3A86D4B402511CFAAC917AC76E",
          "curriculum": {
            "name": "Rising Stars Progression Framework",
            "uuid": "ED5783F62008E54D3F9D5F8B48EE46058679BB9C0907BF8A"
          },
          "subject": {
            "uuid": "91364F1520031DB70162AFEE72134306E4B0D0CC582444B7",
            "name": "Science",
            "source": "system",
            "enabled": true
          },
          "group": {
            "uuid": "EE093F3C20013BAF5B944FFCB2028602613D4CECD876FD34",
            "name": "Class 2",
            "type": "class",
            "policy_priority": 5,
            "users_read_only": false,
            "roles_read_only": false,
            "created_by": null,
            "created_on": 1453125129,
            "updated_by": null,
            "updated_on": 1453189177,
            "source": "local",
            "group_members": [

            ],
            "hidden": false,
            "member_count": 29
          },
          "created_by_uuid": "AEBB466920005BA2486F0FC9F9AAC10FDF77900C90146CF6"
        },
        {
          "uuid": "E88226BA200A731A5E9B6F97C28F1F05A6499EBCA13400D1",
          "curriculum": {
            "name": "Rising Stars Progression Framework",
            "uuid": "ED5783F62008E54D3F9D5F8B48EE46058679BB9C0907BF8A"
          },
          "subject": {
            "uuid": "A6C4DB9E200311439945EF32051D26058C06563C5CA2D536",
            "name": "Writing",
            "source": "system",
            "enabled": true
          },
          "group": {
            "uuid": "EE093F3C20013BAF5B944FFCB2028602613D4CECD876FD34",
            "name": "Class 2",
            "type": "class",
            "policy_priority": 5,
            "users_read_only": false,
            "roles_read_only": false,
            "created_by": null,
            "created_on": 1453125129,
            "updated_by": null,
            "updated_on": 1453189177,
            "source": "local",
            "group_members": [

            ],
            "hidden": false,
            "member_count": 29
          },
          "created_by_uuid": "AEBB466920005BA2486F0FC9F9AAC10FDF77900C90146CF6"
        }
      ],
      "year": {
        "uuid": "E38D758920090CB38EBD5F151EBAEB0305DDD7CC4B0C6E2F",
        "name": "Year 2"
      }
    },
    {
      "trackers": [
        {
          "uuid": "75B0C9D3200A716110AA4F882DC20A0BAC279B8CA0B0DFCD",
          "curriculum": {
            "name": "National Curriculum England 2014 - NAHT Assessment Framework",
            "uuid": "70E1822E2008E7B3BC332F9D56873C0D010F0E7CC6A4BDF4"
          },
          "subject": {
            "uuid": "91364E8D20031F44E5244F062C65370F4736605C0C4B293B",
            "name": "Art and Design",
            "source": "system",
            "enabled": true
          },
          "group": {
            "uuid": "EE093F3C20013BAF5B944FFCB2028602613D4CECD876FD34",
            "name": "Class 2",
            "type": "class",
            "policy_priority": 5,
            "users_read_only": false,
            "roles_read_only": false,
            "created_by": null,
            "created_on": 1453125129,
            "updated_by": null,
            "updated_on": 1453189177,
            "source": "local",
            "group_members": [

            ],
            "hidden": false,
            "member_count": 29
          },
          "created_by_uuid": "AEBB466920005BA2486F0FC9F9AAC10FDF77900C90146CF6"
        },
        {
          "uuid": "E936166D200A71020E0C0F1A02CE140A032E9D7C7AA84CEB",
          "curriculum": {
            "name": "Rising Stars Progression Framework",
            "uuid": "ED5783F62008E54D3F9D5F8B48EE46058679BB9C0907BF8A"
          },
          "subject": {
            "uuid": "91364EE520031CB80E753FE310D95207FE0C6B1CECB022E9",
            "name": "Mathematics",
            "source": "system",
            "enabled": true
          },
          "group": {
            "uuid": "E824756720013148C56DFFD7DD7A12021403CE0CEAB49ED2",
            "name": "Class 1",
            "type": "class",
            "policy_priority": 6,
            "users_read_only": false,
            "roles_read_only": false,
            "created_by": null,
            "created_on": 1453189156,
            "updated_by": null,
            "updated_on": null,
            "source": "local",
            "group_members": [

            ],
            "hidden": false,
            "member_count": 5
          },
          "created_by_uuid": "AEBB466920005BA2486F0FC9F9AAC10FDF77900C90146CF6"
        },
        {
          "uuid": "E912611D200A7B5484DDBF60A382A10023C5B81C92ACFD74",
          "curriculum": {
            "name": "Rising Stars Progression Framework",
            "uuid": "ED5783F62008E54D3F9D5F8B48EE46058679BB9C0907BF8A"
          },
          "subject": {
            "uuid": "A6C4DB8F200316613650CF995B835C06B47CA22CDAAC2F62",
            "name": "Reading",
            "source": "system",
            "enabled": true
          },
          "group": {
            "uuid": "E824756720013148C56DFFD7DD7A12021403CE0CEAB49ED2",
            "name": "Class 1",
            "type": "class",
            "policy_priority": 6,
            "users_read_only": false,
            "roles_read_only": false,
            "created_by": null,
            "created_on": 1453189156,
            "updated_by": null,
            "updated_on": null,
            "source": "local",
            "group_members": [

            ],
            "hidden": false,
            "member_count": 5
          },
          "created_by_uuid": "AEBB466920005BA2486F0FC9F9AAC10FDF77900C90146CF6"
        },
        {
          "uuid": "E922B061200A71FF5F850FB9F28D9001B4DC560C3E96BE13",
          "curriculum": {
            "name": "Rising Stars Progression Framework",
            "uuid": "ED5783F62008E54D3F9D5F8B48EE46058679BB9C0907BF8A"
          },
          "subject": {
            "uuid": "A6C4DB9E200311439945EF32051D26058C06563C5CA2D536",
            "name": "Writing",
            "source": "system",
            "enabled": true
          },
          "group": {
            "uuid": "E824756720013148C56DFFD7DD7A12021403CE0CEAB49ED2",
            "name": "Class 1",
            "type": "class",
            "policy_priority": 6,
            "users_read_only": false,
            "roles_read_only": false,
            "created_by": null,
            "created_on": 1453189156,
            "updated_by": null,
            "updated_on": null,
            "source": "local",
            "group_members": [

            ],
            "hidden": false,
            "member_count": 5
          },
          "created_by_uuid": "AEBB466920005BA2486F0FC9F9AAC10FDF77900C90146CF6"
        }
      ],
      "year": {
        "uuid": "E38D757D2009048C451F4F71C1554E0BADAC8F7C10B2EF1D",
        "name": "Year 1"
      }
    },
    {
      "trackers": [
        {
          "uuid": "47415459200A73E5DF577F0EE2C03705D818E7AC62C37A1A",
          "curriculum": {
            "name": "National Curriculum England 2014 - NAHT Assessment Framework",
            "uuid": "70E1822E2008E7B3BC332F9D56873C0D010F0E7CC6A4BDF4"
          },
          "subject": {
            "uuid": "91364EAF20031403D0DDBF34E5065C0179757BCC6529343C",
            "name": "English",
            "source": "system",
            "enabled": true
          },
          "group": {
            "uuid": "EE093F3C20013BAF5B944FFCB2028602613D4CECD876FD34",
            "name": "Class 2",
            "type": "class",
            "policy_priority": 5,
            "users_read_only": false,
            "roles_read_only": false,
            "created_by": null,
            "created_on": 1453125129,
            "updated_by": null,
            "updated_on": 1453189177,
            "source": "local",
            "group_members": [

            ],
            "hidden": false,
            "member_count": 29
          },
          "created_by_uuid": "EC6B1208200057B15A57FFC60207C608CA49CB5CAC551610"
        },
        {
          "uuid": "8D446D72200A763426C95F326D6F3F0B59D6201C13390095",
          "curriculum": {
            "name": "National Curriculum England 2014 - NAHT Assessment Framework",
            "uuid": "70E1822E2008E7B3BC332F9D56873C0D010F0E7CC6A4BDF4"
          },
          "subject": {
            "uuid": "91364EE520031CB80E753FE310D95207FE0C6B1CECB022E9",
            "name": "Mathematics",
            "source": "system",
            "enabled": true
          },
          "group": {
            "uuid": "EE093F3C20013BAF5B944FFCB2028602613D4CECD876FD34",
            "name": "Class 2",
            "type": "class",
            "policy_priority": 5,
            "users_read_only": false,
            "roles_read_only": false,
            "created_by": null,
            "created_on": 1453125129,
            "updated_by": null,
            "updated_on": 1453189177,
            "source": "local",
            "group_members": [

            ],
            "hidden": false,
            "member_count": 29
          },
          "created_by_uuid": "AEBB466920005BA2486F0FC9F9AAC10FDF77900C90146CF6"
        }
      ],
      "year": {
        "uuid": "E38D758E2009078124015F02F27693054195A99C4654BF09",
        "name": "Year 3"
      }
    }
  ],
  "curriculum_type": {
    "uuid": "AA45156A200924C891166F202DA4960A661567FCF6016269",
    "name": "Key Stages",
    "path": "{\"curriculummanager\":\"year_group,subject,curriculum,subject_area\",\"reporting\":\"year_group,subject\",\"default\":\"year_group,year,subject,curriculum\"}",
    "template": null,
    "created_by": "ADE0C09320005574448F2F024A037A0FB20CDDCC0CCC88D9"
  }
}


],
  "request": {
    "url": "\/studenttracker\/getBy",
    "method": "get",
    "headers": {
      "Host": "future-demo.frogos.net",
      "X-Was-SSL": "true",
      "X-Forwarded-For": "203.34.117.5",
      "Connection": "close",
      "X-AuthType": "oauth_1_0_a",
      "Accept": "application\/json",
      "User-Agent": "FrogProgress\/39 (iPhone; iOS 9.1; Scale\/2.00)",
      "Accept-Language": "en-US;q=1",
      "Accept-Encoding": "*",
      "Authorization": "OAuth          oauth_consumer_key=\"4llu4nfocc6csgkkw84oso8w45tp0z7a\", oauth_nonce=\"845755EC-  B33A-49B3-AE8F-45D58A4BCE92\", oauth_signature=\"5eQIBLO1OvPoLjwWYZCsSV4DfXk%3D\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp=\"1457432571\", oauth_token=\"c85949b632ffde6804317ef17d8f098f8557da43\", oauth_version=\"1.0\""
    },
    "params": [

    ]
  }
}

public class Tracker {

private Response response ;
private String status;

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public Response getResponse() {
    return response;
}

public static class Response {

    private CurriculamType curriculamType;
    private List<Years> years;

    public List<Years> getYears() {
        return years;
    }

    public CurriculamType getCurriculamType() {
        return curriculamType;
    }
}
public static class CurriculamType{

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


}


public static class Years{

    private List<Trackers> trackers;

    public List<Trackers> getTrackers() {
        return trackers;
    }
}


public static class Trackers{


    private List<Subject> subject ;

    public List<Subject> getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }
}


public static class Subject{


    private String name ;
    private String source;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getSource() {
        return source;
    }
}





 }
```

TrackersAPI interface :-

```
public interface TrackersAPI {


@GET("/studenttracker/getBy")
public void getTrackers(Callback<Tracker> response);
}
```

RestAdapter :-

```
RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(ParserMethods.serverURL)
            .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
            .build();

    TrackersAPI api = adapter.create(TrackersAPI.class);

    api.getTrackers(new Callback<Tracker>() {


        @Override
        public void success(Tracker trackers, Response response) {
            loading.dismiss();

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            //you can handle the errors here
            Log.v("Error", error.toString());
        }
    });
```

i think there is an error in my bean class but could not find the solution. Please help!!

Comment: Please show the code that you use to serialize json to object. Your problem lies there.

Comment: I have given the complete code above. Reference : https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/retrofit-android-tutorial-to-get-json-from-server/

Comment: `response` is an array in the JSON while you declared it as single instance `private Response response;` i think you need to change this too `private Response response[];` or as `ArrayList`, i think you have multiple incorrect declaration, your class does not match JSON i suggest a full review and make sure the classes are matching json structure

Comment: try this site http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ it takes JSON as input and generate POJO classes for you. it could be helpful.

Comment: Already did.. But no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

you are getting this error because subject is not an array it is an object while in your tracker code you are considering it as an array.

```
"subject": {
            "uuid": "91364ED12003103FC455BF3B2AC45F0F6387D3FC2A258A05",
            "name": "Computing",
            "source": "system",
            "enabled": true
          },
```

Replace your tracker class subject with below code and hope it will work fine.

```
private Subject subject ;
    public Subject getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry Brother.. no luck. Still get the same error. Please suggest me some other solution..

Comment: Can you please post all the bean class you are using?

Comment: This is the only single class which I am using.

Comment: @DeepakSharma also `response` is an array in the JSON while you declared it as single instance `private Response response ;` i think you need to change this too `private Response response[] ;` or as `ArrayList`

Comment: i think you have multiple incorrect declaration, your class does not match JSON i suggest a full review and make sure the classes are matching json structure

Comment: @Dipak Can you create bean class from your JSON top element, i mean from Status and traverse to end element of the json.

Comment: Can you please put only one element of your JSON response over here?

Comment: I already put only one element as :-

public class TrackerResponse {

    private String status;
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
}

Comment: {
"status": "ok",
"response": [] } reduced your json to given here and try to parse and try to print value of status.

Comment: cant do that as service is build on client side